# if statement/conditions to check a dataframe column for a string in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a column with text like "Dublin 2", "Dublin 4" etc in it. There are up to 24 Dublins that I need to check for.

I want to do something like:

```
if df["Postcode"] == "Dublin 2":
    df["Popularity"] == 10
        
elif df["Postcode"] == "Dublin 3":
    df["Popularity"] == 3
```

etc

I have tried using conditions and np.select, it works but that's not feasible for the number of Dublins I have.

```
conditions = [

    df['Dublin Postcode'].str.contains('Dublin 1'),
    df['Dublin Postcode'].str.contains('Dublin 2'),
    
    ]

values = [10,3]

df['Popularity'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=5)
```

Is there a smarter way of getting it to work? I can't see the wood for the trees at this stage!

Comment: I don't know why my code isn't formatted properly. I hope anyone reading this can understand it!

Comment: I've edited your code blocks. You can see what I changed by clicking on `edited xxx ago` over my name (select 'side-by-side markdown'). You could also select your code and press the `{}` symbol in the editor.

Comment: Upto 24 Dublins. But in the question I do not see the other Popularity values. Are they random or contain a pattern

Comment: I didn't include the other Popularity values, the actual value doesn't really matter

Comment: Then ideally, the oldest answer to this question is already answering it. You can accept it or comment over it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dict from the string to the population like:

`d = {'Dublin 2': 10,...}`

then you can use applay like this:

`df["Popularity"] = df["Postcode"].apply(lambda x: d[x])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

postcode_to_popularity = {"Dublin 2": 10, "Dublin 3": 3} # add your other mappings here
df = pd.DataFrame({"Postcode": ["Dublin 2", "Dublin 3", "Unknwown", "Dublin 2"]}) # here you use your own dataframe
df["Popularity"] = df["Postcode"].apply(lambda postcode: postcode_to_popularity.get(postcode))
print(df)
```

That will give you this:

```sh
   Postcode  Popularity
0  Dublin 2        10.0
1  Dublin 3         3.0
2  Unknwown         NaN
3  Dublin 2        10.0
```

I hope this answers your question !

Comment: Thanks, both those solutions appear to work.